# Need regex that matches a text string that may vary slightly in spacing

Tags: c#, regex, pdf, aspose

As Aspose pulls text from a .pdf I need to identify the number following the string "Check Number:" when there may be one space or two spaces between Check and Number. The program that generates this .pdf is fickle it seems as sometimes there are variations but always the two words Check and Number followed by a colon.  These are followed by an indeterminate amount of spaces and then the actual check number.  I need a regex to plug into my aspose TextFragmentAbsorber. The objective, if not already clearly stated is to capture the entire and correct check number.

```
//create TextAbsorber object to find all the phrases matching the regular expression
TextFragmentAbsorber textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber("\\d{4}-\\d{4}"); //like 1999-2000
```

Comment: I looked at just replacing the text thus: `string text = "foo bar"; text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " "); // text = "foo bar"` But wanted a more robust solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know aspose, but I'll take a shot at it anyway...

First, if you can use capture groups somehow, I guess you could simply use this:

```
new TextFragmentAbsorber(@"Check\s+Number\s*:\s*(?<number>\d{4}-\d{4})");
```

If the whole expression must match the number, you have to use lookbehind:

```
new TextFragmentAbsorber(@"(?<=Check Number:)\s*\d{4}-\d{4}");
```

This solution will include the spaces before the check number, and relies on the fact that there is only a single space between `Check` and `Number`.

If aspose uses the .NET regex engine under the hood, you can use variable length lookbehind expressions:

```
new TextFragmentAbsorber(@"(?<=Check\s+Number\s*:\s*)\d{4}-\d{4}");
```